# Why there is '\' before the parameters in the arm assembly macro?

Tags: macros, arm, assemble

```
    .macro  str_l, src, sym, tmp
#ifndef MODULE
    adrp    \tmp, \sym
    str \src, [\tmp, :lo12:\sym]
#else
    adr_l   \tmp, \sym
    str \src, [\tmp]
#endif
    .endm
```

Above is part of code in the `arch/arm64/include/asm/assembler.h`. And there is `\` before all the parameters. Are they just used to show the names are parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how macros work in the GNU assembler, as explained in [its manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html).  clang is generally compatible with GNU `as` in such things.

The backslash indicates that this use of the macro parameter name should be substituted with its value.